# What is the absolute expected value of the sum of a distribution made up of Bernoulli and Normal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, moment-generating-functions, bernoulli-distribution

$$X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
$$Y \sim Bern(p)$$

$$Z = XY$$

I then have that the pdf of $Z$ is:

$$f(z) = (p-1)\delta(z) + p g(z)$$

where $g(z)$ is the pdf of the normal distribution.

I then need to find the sum of $Q$ of these distributions and finally have to find the expected value of the absolute value of the final resulting distribution.

I do not know where to go from here. I have tried doing it with MGFs but I hit a brick wall with divergent integrals. Any help please?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add that $\frac{Q}{2}$ of these distributions will have the normal with $-\mu$ and the other half with $\mu$. I have tried doing this with a Monte Carlo simulation and then with a similar method to what Henry suggested in the comments.

My simulation has the following results:

| Q | mean | stdev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3.406746 | 3.146736 |
| 4 | 5.156385 | 4.041445 |
| 6 | 6.393295 | 4.865093 |
| 8 | 7.391076 | 5.586568 |
| 10 | 8.283423 | 6.254462 |
| 12 | 9.075857 | 6.846168 |
| 14 | 9.788690 | 7.383987 |
| 16 | 10.471054 | 7.905363 |
| 18 | 11.102388 | 8.384783 |
| 20 | 11.715745 | 8.837827 |

And the equation I got to with the various combinations of folded normal distributions is, where I have used that $p = 0.5$ (if anyone has a more generic solution even better):

**FURTHER EDIT**

I got it for $p = 0.5$, I had made a silly mistake at the start. Thank you all.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Are the resulting $Z_i$ independent of each other? If so, you have the sum of a binomial number of normal distributions, and the absolute value is a mixture of folded normal distributions.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include the equation you got and the results of your simulation.

Comment: Yep, I'm double checking what I have, then I will add if it still doesnt work. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I realised there is a very silly mistake at the beginning of my derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $f(a)=E(|Z-a|)$ if $Z\sim N(0,1)$ Denoting $\Phi(a)=\Pr(Z<a)$ we get $$f(a)=2a\Phi (a)-a+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-a^2/2}.$$ Now let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ independent such that $X_i$ is Bernoulli of mean $p$ and $Y_i=\mu+\sigma Z_i$ with $Z_i\sim N(0,1). $ Note that
$$|Y_1+\cdots+Y_k|=|k\mu+\sigma (Z_1+\cdots+Z_k)|\sim \sqrt{k}\sigma\left|Z_1+\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sigma }\mu\right|$$ since $Z_1+\cdots+Z_k\sim N(0,k)$ and therefore $E(|Y_1+\cdots+Y_k|)=\sqrt{k}\sigma f(-\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sigma }\mu)=g_k.$ To conclude$$E(|X_1Y_1+\cdots+X_nY_n|)=\sum_{k=0}^nC^k_np^k(1-p)^{n-k}g_k.$$

Comment: Thanks, and how can this be modified if there are also another $n$ normal distributions that have opposite $\mu$, where they are still multiplied by a Bernoulli distribution and are all summed together please?

Comment: I am guessing your second line no longer has a $\mu$ factor, but then how does this trickle down to $g_k$? Finally, how would you determine the variance of this please?

Comment: I have made an edit for the variance. Could you more specific about the modifications that you also want to consider? About your second question, note that $g_k$ is a function of $\mu.$

Comment: I can't see the edit for the variance. For my second question I mean that half of the $ X \sim (\mu, \sigma^2) $ while the other half will be $ X' \sim (-\mu, \sigma^2) $. So how would change the final expected value please?

Comment: I was thinking something like
$$ |Y_1+\cdots+Y_k + Y'_1+\cdots+Y'_k|=|\sigma (Z_1+\cdots+Z_k)|\sim \sqrt2{k}\sigma |Z_1| $$
But this does not seem to yield the correct result.

Comment: I have:
$$\mu_S = 2^{-Q/2}\sum_{i,j=0}^{Q/2} \mu_F(\left(i-j\right)\mu, \, (i + j)\sigma^2) {Q/2\choose i}{Q/2\choose j }$$
where $\mu_S$ is the final expected value required, and $\mu_F$ is the expected value of the folded normal given those parameters. However I know this goes $\sim \sqrt{x}$ and I would like to show this. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'IT(?) goes $\sim \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: The equation, plotted w.r.t. $Q$ resembles a function of the form $a+b\sqrt{cx}$ .

Comment: $Z_n=X_1Y_1+\cdots+X_nY_n+X'_1Y'_1+\cdots+X'_nY'_n$ has mean zero and  being the sum of $2n$ independent r.v of the same variance variance $ p^2((\pm\mu)^2)+\sigma^2$ we have $E(Z_n^2)= E(|Z_n|^2)=2np^2(\mu^2+\sigma^2)$ Furthermore the central limit theorem applied to the sum $Z_n$ of the $n$ centered rv variables $X_iY_i+X'iY'_i$ gives that $Z_n/\sqrt{2np^2(\mu^2+\sigma^2))}$ is approximately $N(0,1)$. This explains why $E(|Z_n|)\sim_{n\to \infty} C\sqrt {n}.$

Comment: Yes this makes sense, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i, X_j'\sim Be(p)$, and $Z_i, Z'_j\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_i=\mu+\sigma Z_i,$ $Y'_j=-\mu+\sigma Z_j.$ Then
$$E(|X_1Y_1+\cdots+X_nY_n+X'_1Y'_1+\cdots+X'_nY'_n|)$$$$=\sum_{k=0,r=0}^nC^k_n C^r_np^{k+r}(1-p)^{2n-p-r}E(|(k-r)\mu+\sigma \sqrt{k+r} Z_1|)$$$$=\sum_{k=0,r=0}^nC^k_n C^r_np^{k+r}(1-p)^{2n-p-r} \sqrt{k+r}\sigma f(\frac{r-k}{\sigma \sqrt{k+r}}\mu)$$

Comment: Yes, this makes sense thank you. Finally, how can I determine the variance of this distribution please?

Comment: The expection of the square is $2np(\mu^2+\sigma^2).$

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented this and it is slightly off compared to the expression I provided in your previous post. Do you happen to have your calculations for this like you did previously so I can go through them please? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you have a mistake in your expression it should be:
$$(1-p)^{2n-k-r}$$
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I can't seem to get the correct expression for the variance using your expression for the expectation of the square. Do you have any insight please?

Comment: I don't know how you get the variance, I do by Huyghens: $\sigma^2(X) =E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.$

Comment: Yes I adapted your expression for the expectation of the square to:

$$ \sum_{k=0, r=0}^n C_n^k C_n^r p^{k+r} (1-p)^{2n-k-r} 2np((k-r)^2\mu^2 + (k+r)\sigma^2) $$

or has this been done incorrectly?